# How do I get the tablet gmail client to allow me to swipe to archive like the phone client

Tags: gmail, tablet

I have a HTC One V and a Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 - in the One V, I can archive a message by swiping it. On the galaxy tab, I need to select the message, and hit the swipe button. The phone runs android 4.01, and the tablet runs 4.1

Is there any way I can get the tablet gmail client to behave like the phone gmail client?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the issue was resolved by an update. My mother's Galaxy tab runs gmail 4.1.2, mine seems to have been updated to 4.3 at some point, and one of the things this update did is add swipe to archive.

The answer seems to be, "get the newer version"